# How can one reuse similar but different class properties

Tags: c#, class, properties

I would like to know the best practice to handle the below situation in C#.NET:

I have a Table Client

```
ClientId
LastUpdatedBy
LastUpdatedOn
```

So I created a class having properties

```
class Client
{      
    Guid ClientId {get; set;}    
    Guid LastUpdatedBy {get; set;}  
    DateTime LastUpdatedOn {get; set;}
}
```

Similarly, I have a Table Project

```
ProjectId 
LastUpdatedBy   
LastUpdatedOn
```

So I created a Project class having properties:

```
class Project
{     
    Guid ProjectId {get; set;}    
    Guid LastUpdatedBy {get; set;}  
    DateTime LastUpdatedOn {get; set;}
}
```

Likewise, I have around 100 more table and all possess these `LastUpdatedBy` and `LastUpdatedOn` columns.

In the code, is it right to create a property of these columns in each class or is there a way, I can generalize these properties and utilize those in each class? If so, An example would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well simply rename `ProjectId` and `ClientId` `Id` and use a base abstract class

```
abstract class ClassBase
{
     protected Guid Id {get; set;}
     protected Guid LastUpdatedBy {get; set;}
     protected DateTime LastUpdatedOn {get; set;}
}
```

Then:

```
class Client : ClassBase
{
}

class Project : ClassBase
{
}
```

Comment: Yes use a common base class to share common properties and avoid duplication.

Answer (score 4):

That's what inheritance is for:

```
public class BaseEntity
{
  Guid LastUpdatedBy {get; set;}  
  DateTime LastUpdatedOn {get; set;}
}

public class Client: BaseEntity
{
  Guid ClientId {get; set;}    
}
```

Comment: I appreciate your timely response and also understand what inheritance is meant for!! I am looking for suggestions and want to know what would be good for my situation. So you suggest I create a generic class and all classes must inherit from it. Right?

Comment: In a nutshell, yes. I would also advise getting some good books on object-oriented design. (CLR via C#, Essential C#, Clean Code, Head-First Design Patterns are some of my favorites)